# error 1009 on Apple Watch when I used URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession, apple-watch-standalone

I have the error 1009 "it seems network was disconnected" when I used URLSession.shard.data(from: URL) on my Apple Watch S7(watchOS9.1_20S75), no cellar edition but really connected to wi-fi.

I have committed a Technical Support Incident (TSI), and replied by Quinn “The Eskimo!” (Apple Developer Relations, Developer Technical Support, Core OS/Hardware)
He gave me an example project that works on his own device in his office, this is the code, but the project really not works on my watch!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var dataStr: String = "..."

    var body: some View {
        Button("start") {
            Task {
                do {
                    dataStr = "..."
                    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: URL(string: "https://www.baidu.com")!)
                    let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
                    dataStr = "status: \(httpResponse.statusCode), count: \(data.count)"
                } catch {
                    dataStr = error.localizedDescription.description
                }
            }
        }
        Text(dataStr)
    }
}
```

I guess that it's the local wi-fi configuration that makes our difference, I even failed to visit the local http server with http://(myMacIpInTheSameLocalNetwork) when I open "Allow Arbitrary Loads" Setting.

It frustrated me, that means I have to think it's the only solution I can adapt to use Bonjour Service just like the TicTacToe sample project provided by Apple Development Document, when my watch needs to communicate with other device nearby.

However, I realized that some standalone watch apps like uBrowser could work successfully on my watch under my wi-fi environment! Could any one tell me how to make it?

Comment: I had to guess a bit as to the correct tags; please review.